# Using the factorization method with variables.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Suppose that in standard factored form a =$ p_1^{e_1}p_2^{e_2}\cdots p_k^{e_k}$, where
k ,
where k is a positive integer; $p_1, p_2, \dots , p_k$ are prime numbers;
and $e_1, e_2,\dots, e_k$ are positive integers.

a. What is the standard factored form for $a^2$?

b. Find the least positive integer $n$ such that $25 \cdot3\cdot 52 \cdot 73 \cdot n$
is a perfect square. Write the resulting product as a perfect
square.

c. Find the least positive integer $m$ such that
$22 \cdot35 \cdot7\cdot11\cdot m$ is a perfect square. Write the resulting
product as a perfect square.

Does anyone know how the factorization is used in a. I am very lost in this problem. How can one break up variables, in the standard form?

Comment: Square both sides to get a prime factorization for $\,a^2\,$ (there can be no other by the *uniqueness* of prime factorizations). So a natural is a square iff each prime occurs to even power in its prime factorization. Use this to solve (b) and (c), i.e. which prime factors need to be appended to obtain all even prime powers?

Comment: oh I see so if it is a^2 then that means that all the other variables are squared as well. $p1^e1$ becomes p1^2e

Comment: Also the 1 under it does not change because all it is a symbol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $$a=p_1^{e_1}p_2^{e_2}p_3^{e_3}\cdots p_k^{e_k}$$ $$\implies
      a^2=(p_1^{e_1}p_2^{e_2}p_3^{e_3}\cdots p_k^{e_k})^2$$
   $$a^2=p_1^{2e_1}p_2^{2e_2}p_3^{2e_3}\cdots p_k^{2e_k}$$

   ---
2. $$25\cdot 3\cdot 52\cdot 73\cdot n=5^2\cdot 3\cdot (2^2\cdot 13)\cdot 73\cdot n$$
   We need to make the power of every prime number in this to be even
   The minimum number required for this is $$n=3\cdot 13\cdot 73$$
   The resulting number will be $$2^2\cdot 3^2\cdot 5^2\cdot 13^2\cdot 73^2$$
   $$=28470^2=810540900$$

   ---
3. This problem is effectively same as the one above. You try this one.

Comment: So for c you say m^2 = 149688 then take the square root and get 387. which equals 43*9.

Comment: @LittleJon Just follow step by step what I did in the second one. Find the prime factorization of the number, Find all the factors which don't have an even exponent, choose $m$ accordingly so that their exponent becomes even